# HTTP status code returned by Laravel application in IIS

Tags: php, laravel, http, fastcgi, iis-10

I been trying to configure a REST API written with PHP and Laravel for a few days, but I can't get the correct HTTP status code according to the error returned (401, 404, 500, etc).

IIS always replaces the http status code with 200 no matter what I do.

I added the configuration below to my `web.config` file, but it's still not successful.

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

Below the complete file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My version of IIS:

[IIS Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9G75.png)

**An important observation is that the same application behaves normally using Apache or Nginx.**

Is there any additional configuration that must be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: You might want to see into those 200 responses with FRT and learn what changed the error codes to 200, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing Without that no one can help further, as they won't be able to reproduce this.

Comment: Are the returned errors custom errors? if so, "PassThrough" means leaves the response untouched if an existing response exists. Hence, it breaks your custom errors. You can try the "Auto" option which leaves the response untouched only if the SetStatus flag is set.

Comment: @samwu I'm trying to return a JSON with a certain HTTP code. In this example it would be an HTTP 500.

I added the "Auto" option but got the same return (a JSON with HTTP code 200).

Comment: Then you can follow lex's suggestion to use failed request tracking to view detailed request information.